# What is the contemporary usage of the word "blouse", namely in North America?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, north-american-english

I've red some definitions of the word "blouse" and not all of them agree. From Wikipedia

> A blouse is a loose-fitting upper garment that was formerly worn by
>   workmen, peasants, artists, women and children.[1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blouse?q=blouse) It is typically
>   gathered at the waist (by a waistband or belt) so that it hangs
>   loosely ("blouses"[2](http://supersklep.com/i127980-element-t-shirt-man-machine-sea)) over the wearer's body.[1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blouse?q=blouse) Today, the word most
>   commonly refers to a woman's shirt[3] but can also refer to a man's
>   shirt if it is a loose-fitting style (e.g. poet shirts and Cossack
>   shirts).[4] Traditionally, the term has been used to refer to a shirt
>   which blouses out or has an unmistakably feminine appearance.

From the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blouse?q=blouse)

> a woman’s upper garment resembling a shirt, typically with a collar,
>   buttons, and sleeves. 1) loose linen or cotton garment formerly worn by
>   peasants and manual workers, typically belted at the waist. 2) type of
>   jacket worn as part of military uniform.

It appears to be technically correct to say a blouse can be a man's article of clothing, but is this accepted in common usage? For example would it be considered offensive (or feminine) to describe a loose t-shirt a man is wearing as a blouse? The following picture is of a man wearing a loose t-shirt but I don't think many would consider it a blouse:

http://supersklep.com/i127980-element-t-shirt-man-machine-sea (image upload not working)

Comment: Definately not a blouse. That's a t-shirt and nothing else.  Unless you are speaking from a specific context in which it is usual to call the thing a man wears a blouse (and I don't know of any) don't ever call it a blouse if it's a piece of guys clothing.

Comment: It is certainly used in French to mean a man's short jacked e.g. 'blouson d'aviateur'. Young men of the 1950s sub-culture in France, a bit like the British 'Teddy Boys', were known as 'les blousons noirs', from the black jackets they wore.

Comment: A t-shirt is never a blouse, because the following is essential: *"with a collar, buttons, and sleeves".*

Comment: @Cerberus the definition says "typically with" so not necessarily...

Comment: Celeritas - That "typically with" is to allow for a blouse like [this one](http://moneysavingmom.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/41pveQYhJbL._SL316_.jpg), which is sleeveless and without buttons. But @Cerberus is exactly right when he points out that a t-shirt is never a blouse, because the "typically with" part is essential. A t-shirt is a t-shirt and not a blouse.

Comment: @J.R.: Yeah, and I would hesitate to call that thing a blouse, actually.

Comment: @Cerberus - Well, that's what the [website](http://moneysavingmom.com/2010/10/target-com-womens-ruffle-neck-blouse-for-7-20-shipped.html) calls it. But I think we can agree that he's not wearing a blouse, and she's not wearing a t-shirt! :^)

Comment: @J.R.: What do websites know...but, yes, let's agree on what they're *not*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, *blouse* is regularly used to refer to women's shirts.  It is never used to refer to men's civilian clothing. It is sometimes used for men's military uniform shirts, but not T-shirts.

Comment: *Blouse* may also be used technically for some non-military uniforms as well.  But probably only in the garment business, not among the people wearing them.

Comment: @GEdgar - Spot on. I never donned a blouse for work – no matter what the lady at the dry cleaners wrote on the slip.

Comment: @J.R.: No matter what kind of flowers and pink patterns were on it...but, yeah, shops use the darnedest words.

Comment: Not to mention the buttons being on the wrong side...

Comment: @polarysekt Too bad for us left-handers.

Comment: When I was in the military from 1965 to 1972 during the Vietnam war most of the services called the jacket, not shirt of our military uniform as a blouse in confirming the latter part of the definition.